# Plesk API to call for email alias and display in roundcube

Tags: xml, plesk

I'm trying to make this plugin for Roundcube that you can manage email aliases but I'm running into a little bit of a problem. When I call to fetch the email aliases it's only showing the first one and ignoring any other ones that are available. For example, one of my email address has 4 aliases but it's only showing the first alias and ignoring the rest.

This is the code that I have so far:

```html
$plek_email = <<<EOF
<packet>
    <mail>
        <get_info>
            <filter>
          <site-id>$plesk_client_domain</site-id>
        </filter>
            <mailbox/>
            <aliases/>
        </get_info>
    </mail>
</packet>
EOF;
        
        $plesk_email_response = new SimpleXMLElement($plesk_client->request($plek_email));
        foreach ($plesk_email_response->mail->get_info->result->mailname as $mailname) {
            $plesk_client_email = $mailname->alias;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to loop trough all the alias elements in the response XML output from the API.

Like so:

```
    foreach($response->mail->get_info->result->mailname->alias as $alias) {
          print_r($alias);
    }
```

Comment: I've tried that, but that only adds XML response at the header of the page.

SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => admin ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => shopping ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => contact ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => postmaster ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => root ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => root )